# How to select from one table non existing data in second table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 2 tables :

tab1
tab2
Here's the rows included in those table

tab1

```
item| num
a   | 2
a   | 3
b   | 1
b   | 3
```

tab2

```
num
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

There is a reference between the num in tab1 and num in tab2.
How to select nums from tab2 that dont exist in tab1 with the item column?

Here is the desired result:

```
item | num
a    | 1
a    | 4
a    | 5
b    | 2
b    | 4
b    | 5
```

Comment: your tab b doesn't contain item column in given example

Comment: yes it doesnt have, i am using tab2 as a list of numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be anti-join, using a "calendar" table containing all possible num/item values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1a.item,
    t2.num
FROM tab2 t2
CROSS JOIN tab1 t1a
LEFT JOIN tab1 t1b
    ON t1b.item = t1a.item AND
       t1b.num = t2.num
WHERE
    t1b.item IS NULL
ORDER BY
    t1a.item,
    t2.num;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo